# How to get active member count Discord JS

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a function which counts all active members on active server

I've tried to get into `client.guilds.cache` then filter users by their `presence.status` to check if the user is online. As far as I am aware what's happening `.size` should return a number of active members on the server, but instead it returns 0, no matter what I try.

Here's the code I've tried

I call function in `client.on` here and pass client as an argument

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers],
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    activeMembersCounter(client)
});
```

Then in `activeMembersCounter.ts`

```
function activeMembersCounter(client: Client<boolean>): void {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(config.GUILD_ID);
    const onlineMembers = guild.members.cache.filter((m) => m.presence?.status === "online"&& !member.user.bot).size;
    console.log(onlineMembers) // logs 0 
}
```

I've also tried `async` version with `fetch`

```
async function activeMembersCounter(client: Client<boolean>): Promise<void> {
    const guild = client.guilds.cache.get(config.GUILD_ID);
    const onlineMembers = (await guild.members.fetch()).filter((member) => member.presence?.status === "online" && !member.user.bot);
    console.log(onlineMembers.size);
}
```

I'm not 100% sure if my approach is correct here. I would love to get some advice :)

Comment: I think you need to enable the presence intent

Comment: Privileged Gateway Intents:
PRESENCE INTENT is on,  SERVER MEMBERS INTENT is on,   MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT is also on, every intents I could enable, is enabled

Comment: It has to be enabled in the array when you're constructing the `Client` too.

Comment: Im able to get `guild.memberCount` but Im not able to reach to `guild.members` ?

Comment: Not all members are cached by default. To forcefully cache all members, use `await guild.members.fetch()` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things you need to change.

1. Use the GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences flag, m.presence returns null if you don't use it.
2. member is undefined in your online members variable. Use m.user.bot instead of member.user.bot.

Working code:

```
const { GatewayIntentBits, Client} = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences],
});



function activeMembersCounter(c) {
  const guild = c.guilds.cache.get("GUILD_ID");
  console.log(guild);
  const onlineMembers = guild.members.cache.filter((m) => m.presence?.status == "online" && !m.user.bot).size;
  console.log(onlineMembers);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
  activeMembersCounter(client);
})
```

Edit: If you're looking for active members, this could include DND members and Idle members. You might want to consider using `m.presence?.status != "offline"` instead of `m.presence?.status == "online"` to include these other statuses in your count.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include DND && Idle members you need to use `m.presence?.status != null` rather than using `m.presence?.status != "offline"`